# What files should I add to the .gitignore when using MATLAB and Simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink, gitignore

I would like to know what files I should add to the `.gitignore` file when I am using MATLAB and Simulink.

Should the files `slx.original` be added?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Github has a nice [gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/) repo

Specifically for Matlab projects, the [template](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/MATLAB.gitignore) is:

```
##---------------------------------------------------
## Remove autosaves generated by the Matlab editor
## We have git for backups!
##---------------------------------------------------

# Windows default autosave extension
*.asv

# OSX / *nix default autosave extension
*.m~

# Compiled MEX binaries (all platforms)
*.mex*

# Simulink Code Generation
slprj/

# Session info
octave-workspace

# Simulink autosave extension
.autosave
```

Comment: What about files with *.autosave, *.slx.original extension?

Comment: you could include those as well and provide a PR to the original repo if that's usual in Matlab/Simulink development, which I haven't touched in a while